# MIPS Assembly Language - Base64 Encoding?

Tags: assembly, encoding, base64, mips

The point of this program is to base64 encode a string that's been provided by the user, and then output the new encoded string.

The encoding is done by gathering 3 chars from the original string (each char being 8 bits) and then splitting them among 4 chars of 6 bits each.

How to properly access and manipulate the user-inputted string?

Currently the first iteration brings the correct output, but the second iteration always gives t2 the value "0", no matter the input, which stops the program with output A; both of which are wrong.

```
.data
sentence: .space 64
prompt: .asciiz "Enter the string: "
ASC: .byte    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','+','/'

.text
.globl main

main:

la $s0, ASC

la $a0, prompt      #ask for string
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 8            #take string
la $a0, sentence     #load byte space into address
li $a1, 64       #max number of bytes
syscall

la $t0, sentence    
lb $t2, 0($t0)          #to load the first 8 bits   

j read_ASC

read_ASC: beq $t2, $0, exit

lb $t2, 0($t0)          #to load the first 8 bits
andi $a0, $t2, 63   #takes first 6 bits of string
    #srl $t0, $t0, 6    #removes the 6 bits we just took
sub $t0, $t0, $t2   #removes the char we just took

addu $t1, $a0, $s0  #s0 being the base of the table, $a0 being the offset

#lbu $a0, ASC($a0)
lbu $a0, 0($t1)     #sees value of the 6 bits from string to retrieve encoded value from table

li $v0, 11      #prints the new encoded char
syscall

j read_ASC

exit:   li $v0, 10      #end
syscall
```

Comment: The error would say: cannot read directly from text segment.
Also, I tried lw $t2, 0($t0) instead of lb, and the program would run forever instead outputting "A" only, which is the first element of my table

Comment: Are you using MARS simulator, or one of SPIM ones? In MARS in debugger you can see memory content, although only grouped as "words" (32 bit = 4 bytes values), so it's a bit more difficult to read strings (because string "ABCDEF\n\0" is stored as 8 bytes `41 42 43 44 45 46 0A 00`, but when viewed as little-endian words that's two words `44434241 000A4645` (all values hexa of course, so you can see individual byte values easily). So you can try to input some string, and then see yourself in the memory view, how that string is there, but you already seems to understand each char is 1 byte.

Comment: @Samer Basta: Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50904256/edit) your question and add these new information to it, you should not post it as a comment to your own question. Thanks.

Comment: So your `lb $t2, 0($t0)` makes sense. I wouldn't say that about `beq $t0, $0, exit` = why do you compare memory address against zero? You can't have "nullptr" there, as you did `la $t0, sentence` right before. Then you don't advance the `t0` memory address, so you will keep reading same memory spot. Also `andi $a0, $t2, 6` makes no sense, the `andi` is bit-wise operator, the "6" is in binary `0...0110`, so you keep only two bits of the original value, not 6 of them.

Comment: About *"cannot read directly from text segment."* Are you sure you know at which instruction that happens? Did you single-step over your code? It's unlikely it's the `lb` thing, seems correct to me (although I didn't try to run it, maybe I'm overlooking something, like some kind of syntax typo)... at least the first iteration through your code should actually somewhat work, so if you are single stepping over it in debugger and the `lb` fails, check what was that source memory address where it failed and describe precisely what exactly you are trying and what you see.

Comment: @Ped7g oh yes you're right, I should change beq $t0 to $t2, correct? And I should andi 63 instead of 6, to read the first 6 bits, yeah?

Comment: @Ped7g the first iteration does work. Not correctly because it gives the result "A", when it should be "b" (I put in the word "maybe" for testing my program). During the second iteration is gives the error at:    lb $t2, 0($t0)

Comment: yes, testing `t2` against zero value makes more sense, although AFTER you will load the value from memory ;) ... why the `lb` fails in second iteration is mystery to me, I don't see anything which would modify `t0` meanwhile, so you are probably testing different code than posted. But it's like super easy to see in debugger, what every register contains, so you should just keep track of everything during first iteration, if every instruction does, what was expected and fits your original algorithm design. So then you can track how `t0` address did change and why.

Comment: I see you did edit the code meanwhile, so my comments may be obsolete now, which is fine, keep narrowing down your question/confusion, the more specific it will be, the more likely is you will get some answer (or you will figure out yourself).

Comment: Also doesn't Base64 encode bits from left, i.e. you need top-most 6 bits from first byte for first char? Too lazy to check myself, but put into google some "online base64 conversion", and prepare few testing strings for yourself, where you fully understand every bit of input/output, so you know what you should get out of your code.. maybe use paper to help yourself to better understand the input/output pairs on bit level, so you can then better recognize in debugger if your asm code does manipulate the bits in the way you need. (and `lb` is sign-extending the value! 255 = 0xFFFFFFFF then)

Comment: @Ped7g yes Base64 encodes from le
ft to right, which is why I have t2 load byte from the top of my string! Right now my main problem is that I'm not sure how to manipulate user inputted strings properly

Comment: Well, you are already reading first byte of it properly. What do you mean "manipulate", you are just reading it, then producing output, not truly modifying it. But you need to read 3 bytes to output 4 chars, which makes it a bit more tricky with data of lengths not divisible by 3. For the moment I would suggest you focus on simple 3-byte long inputs and work out on bit levels what is required to do, on paper first, then make some sort of algorithm/plan how to achieve that, then start to write code for it. The non-div-3 data can be resolved later. Advance in small steps, when you understand..

Comment: Your latest addition `sub $t0, $t0, $t2   #removes the char we just took` makes no sense... `t0` is memory address, some number like 123431, subtracting char value `(like `'A'` is 65) will produce address like 123431-65 = 123366 ... = makes no sense. You need to read 3 bytes from addresses 123431, 123432 and 123433, and convert those into 4 characters. The value of encoded character doesn't affect memory address to read next 8 data bits. Your original idea with shift instruction made more sense, but you need then to merge 2 bits from first byte and 4 bits from second. Use shift/and/or.

Comment: I.e. it seems you are struggling with the basic computer architecture things, like what is memory, how it is addressed, what are bits, bytes, etc... Answering such questions is a bit annoying, as usually it's both difficult to guess the level of the OP, i.e. how much to explain basics, and also the answers grow quickly in size being too broad, or replacement of proper tutorial/book. You seem to be doing excellent progress just from these comments, maybe it's good time for you to re-read some tutorial/book again about the basics + check some examples in debugger single-stepping over them.